# how do i import a list from a .py file from GitHub using a python script

Tags: python, github, python-import

I'm a beginner in python and am currently practicing with a new program that access a list on-line so it can use it from any device

So just like you would import a list form a .py file on your project's folder, I tried importing the file from a GitHub repository. The only thing I managed to do is to get a string with the list. `b"names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']\r\n"`

Comment: Why not just download the GitHub repo?

Comment: bc when I'm done making the script I want to be able to access it on any device without having to download anything besides the script itself